# What's happening to my DAC signal here?

Tags: embedded, dac

I have an [Atmel ATmega328P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) using a [14-Bit MAXIM MAX544 DAC](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX544-MAX545.pdf).

I have the ADC configured and running at 38kHz in running mode while the SPI is clocked at 4 MHz. I feel this should be more than equate for a 4 kHz + signal.

- Is my DAC bottle necking here?
- Why is my signal looking at that as its under sampling?  And:
- why isn't the 4.3 kHz signal not looking like the 50Hz one?

[image]
Figure 1: Sin Wave: 50Hz 
[image]
Figure 2: Sin Wave: 4.4kHz
[image]
Figure 3: SinWave: 20kHz
   EDIT: The positive cycle is only present due to no biasing being implemented.

```
#include <SPI.h>;

unsigned short x;

void setup() {
  DDRD |= 0x08;
  DDRB |= 0x04;
  DDRC |= 0x00;
  PORTD |= 0x08;

  ADMUX = 0x00;
  ADCSRA = 0xAD;
  ADCSRB = 0x00;
  ADCSRA |= 0x40;

  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setBitOrder (MSBFIRST);
  PORTB = 0x04;
}

ISR(ADC_vect) {
   x = ADCL | (ADCH << 8);   
   PORTB = 0x00;
   SPI.transfer(x);
   PORTB = 0x04;
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: It's not under sampling at all. Looks like what you get at the sampling frequency you are operating at.

Comment: Let me retake the second photo. Its doing no justice.

Comment: @Andyaka So thats normal?

Comment: @Pllsz What exactly is the problem? You have a 4.3kHz waveform sampled at about 10x that rate, and are seeing about 5 samples in a +ve half cycle. Looks spot-on to me. Once you've been through the standard anti-aliasing filter that cuts off somewhere above 4.3kHz and below 19kHz, you'll see the second trace look like the first. The first trace doesn't look like the second because you've much finer  timebase resolution, and there's so little voltage between steps.

Comment: Yup, still looks normal.

Comment: @Neil_UK Oh? Its all because its zoomed in more?

Comment: Let me post a  20 kHz one

Comment: 20 kHz is aliasing. It’s bad but explainable. Go google signal aliasing.

Comment: Okay. Will do .

Comment: Your signal processing and DAC are behaving perfectly, even at 20kHz fout. Now you just have to update your expectations of what you actually get before the anti-aliasing filter, with modest oversampling ratios. If you have some graphical software, Matlab, python+matplotlib, heck you can even use Excel, plot out what you see at the DAC output. You'll see just these pictures.

Comment: I see, it looks like just my inexperience is the fault here. How would one get a almost perfect original signal then? Reconstruction filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is my signal looking at that as its under sampling?

It doesn't look undersampled, rather you have no reconstruction filter so you get a stair-step waveform.  Add the filter and you'll get the expected reconstructed signal.

> why isn't the 4.3 kHz signal not looking like the 50Hz one?

Because you changed the time base on your oscilloscope.  A combination of filtering your scope at lower frequencies and/or undersampling gives you something that looks more like the output of a reconstruction filter.  Zoom back in and you should see that it is still a stair-step.

Comment: I see I see. Thank you. Is a reconstruction filter always needed ?

Comment: No, not always needed.  Lots of times it is enough to leave the signal the way you have it now.  By the way, sampling, aliasing, reconstruction are all things that are worth reading about if you're going to be using a DAC.

Comment: I see. Thank you once again. Yeah looks like be reading about it.